# How can I connect my Windows laptop's keyboard to my iPad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, windows

I have a Windows laptop and an iPad Air 3. I want a physical keyboard for my iPad but I don't want to carry around another Bluetooth keyboard.

Is there a way that I can use my laptop as an external keyboard for my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at an App called [AirType](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/airtype-type-from-your-computer/id922932291).  According to the developer, it works on Mac, Windows and Linux machines and the requirements are iOS 8 and above as well as both devices being on the same network.